# REST url filtering

Tags: rest, url, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I am working within a Sharepoint workflow, and am making a call using REST api to a Sharepoint list. The issue is that this list has over 450 items in it.  The workflow wants to pull in all the entries and search which of them have a specific entry in a field.  Due to the mass number of list items, the workflow runs out of memory.  How can I change my REST call to only pull in  list items that have specific values in a field so I don't have to hold all of the entries within the workflow variables?

Comment: Sharepoint REST supports ODATA syntax for this purpose.  Can you show an example of your call to get the entire list?  The following: http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2013/09/05/working-with-sharepoint-list-data-odata-rest-and-javascript.aspx looks like a good source of examples.

Comment: The following also looks like a nice approach to investigating the ODATA in SP and then applying ODATA query values to the lists: http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Querying-and-exploring-REST-API-with-oData-in-SharePoint-2013-with-DataBase-net.aspx

Comment: https://_______.com/sites/siteHere/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items

Comment: https://_______.com/sites/siteHere/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items$filter=someColumn eq 'someValue'

Comment: neither ?$filter=‌​TaskStatus eq 'Not Started'                
nor $filter=‌​TaskStatus eq 'Not Started'   
worked, just said they were invalid. This was largely the same   format I was attempting before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [SharePoint REST service supports a wide range of OData query string operators that enable you to select, filter, and order the data you request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx), you could provide a specific query for a `Call HTTP Web Service` workflow activity.

Using `$filter` query option you could select which items to return, for example the following query returns only items from `Contacts` list those email address contains `@contoso.com`:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Contacts')/items?$filter=substringof('@contoso.com',Email)
```

Further optimization would be to specify which fields to return. Use `$select` query option for that purpose, for example the following query returns only `Email` and `FullName` fields:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Contacts')/items?$filter=substringof('@contoso.com',Email)&$select=Email,FullName
```

### References

[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx)